# Publishing Audio from iPhone to HTTP

Tags: iphone, networking, iphone-sdk-3.0, streaming

I have read that Apple has allowed iPod Library Access in iPhone OS 3.0 and thus an App can access the data stored in the iPod.

I want to know that is there a possibility that the audio being played by an App can be published over a Network Stream.

Let me know your thoughts.

Thanks and Regards,

Muhammad Haseeb Khan

Answer (score 0):

Can't be done. That "access" is very limited and does not include the audio data.

You *can* however broadcast, say, the playlist or the album art.

It really does open up a whole *world* of possibilities.

Comment: Then, it means that the Audio can't be published. Publishing Playlist or Audio Art is not something we are looking at.
Lets see if Apple opens up the API in near future.